# Foundation 5 - loading javascript components on single page web app

Tags: zurb-foundation

I have a single page app using ajax to load pages. I'm using Foundation 5 as the framework. My question is why don't the foundation components load when a new page is loaded to the dom?

For example, I'm using several components like Reveal, Alert, Abide and Tooltip. I was able to get the alert component to fire by adding this:

```
<script>
$(document).foundation('alert','events');
</script>
```

But how do I just get everything to fire?

Comment: Try calling `$(document).foundation();` each time your DOM reloads.

Comment: Could you be more specific on how to achieve that? Right now I have index.html which is where the new pages get loaded. And this is where I have $(document).foundation();